# Read values from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object, loops

I am currently trying to get contents from a JSON object.
I've been looking all over google and what I think should work, for some reason, does not.

The JSON looks something like this:

```
{"locatie0":{"naam0":["Domplein"],"value0":["value1"]},"locatie1":{"naam1":["Neude"],"value1":["value1"]},"locatie2":{"naam2":["Vredenburg"],"value2":["value1"]},"locatie3":{"naam3":["Stadhuisbrug"],"value3":["value1"]},"locatie4":{"naam4":["Korte Minrebroederstraat"],"value4":["value1"]}}
```

I use below code to read the file but for some reason it will always return undefined or NaN.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "_data/pleinen.json",
    type: 'get', 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(data) {
        for(var k = 0; k < _loc.length; k += 1) {
            var _locaties = data.locatie[k].naam[k];
            // Should alert "Domplein", "Neude", "Vredenburg", "Stadhuisbrug", "Korte Minrebroekstraat", 
            alert(_locaties);
        }
    }
});
```

Can anybody see if i've made any mistakes in my code or if there's a better way to read the values?

Comment: given the json you should acces data.locatie0/1/2... and not data.locatie (if it is not a typo).

Comment: you dnt have an array named locatie in json!!!

Comment: Any reason for the -1?

Comment: @user1654209 I want to access them dynamically. Setting it statically kindoff removes the whole point of the for loop.

Comment: @555k Thanks for the insightfull comment, but I knew this. My problem is how I get the values from the naam and value fields, not the philosophy behind my json object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`locatie[k]` tries to access the property `k` of the object in `locatie`, but in your case, the number is part of the name itself. You have to build the property name dynamically. In addition, each property of the nested objects is an array with one element, so you have to access the first element:

```
var _locaties = data['locatie' + k]['naam' + k][0];
```

Your data structure is a bit strange though. The numbers in the property names makes accessing the data more difficult. If you can change it, change it to an array of objects and don't use arrays for the properties if you don't need them:

```
[{"naam": "Domplein", "value": "value1"}, {"naam": "Neude", "value":"value1"}]
```

Then accessing the data is simply:

```
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    var _locaties = data[i].naam;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know my structure is off, but I'm not that good at creating arrays. To clarify, I'm making an array somewhere else (backoffice), turn it into json with json_encode and write it to a file, after which I read the file in my application.

Comment: Well, you just have to create the array properly in PHP (I assume because you mentioned `json_enode`) ;) Having indexes in names is a clear sign for a bad structure, because that's what arrays are for. Each element in an array already has an index. It's worth spending some time and creating the structure properly, it will be easier for you to maintain your code in the long run.

Comment: I've fixed the code where the json gets generated and saved to the file. Now I can use `data['locatie' +k]['naam']` to access the `naam` field. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `locatie` and the `naam` are not arrays, so you cannot access them like the way you do.

You have to combine the number with the name as a string. Something like that

```
data['locatie'+k]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "_data/pleinen.json",
    type: 'get', 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(data) {
        for(var k = 0; k < _loc.length; k += 1) {
            var _locaties = data['locatie'+k]['naam'+k][0]; 
            alert(_locaties);
        }
    }
});
```

As the value of `naam` property is array you need to fetch first item from it in order to get string value.

Answer (score 2):

A JSON does not guarantee any order like an array.

But in your case, the keys of the JSON have index hints, so try accessing "naam" with:

```
 data["locatie" + k]["naam" + k]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ;

```
k = 0;
console.log( 
    data[ 'locatie'+ k]['naam'+ k][0], 
    data[ 'locatie'+ k]['value'+ k ][0]
);

k = 1;
console.log( 
    data[ 'locatie'+ k]['naam'+ k][0], 
    data[ 'locatie'+ k]['value'+ k ][0]
);
```