# Can't figure out how to loop through a JavaScript array and check each item

Tags: javascript

Tried searching for the various types of JavaScript array access but didn't find for this type of an array.

```
[
{
    "id": "bar",
    "data": [
        {
            "x": "info",
            "y": 4826
        },
        {
            "x": "error",
            "y": 4823
        },
        {
            "x": "warn",
            "y": 4751
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "pie",
    "data": [
        {
            "key": "info",
            "y": 4826
        },
        {
            "key": "error",
            "y": 4823
        },
        {
            "key": "warn",
            "y": 4751
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "pie",
    "data": [
        {
            "key": "info",
            "y": 510
        },
        {
            "key": "error",
            "y": 600
        },
        {
            "key": "warn",
            "y": 185
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Have to loop through an array and know which type of chart is it(scan of id element)
Help me out..

Comment: JSON is JSON, surely. Once you've parsed the JSON you have JavaScript objets, no matter the structure of the data.

Comment: I think you're talking about traversing, or just generally retrieving data. That's not parsing.

Comment: Why don't you use JSON.parse() to create an array an search/loop the resulting array?

Comment: Anyway, from your last sentence in the question, it seems that you already know what needs to be done. So where's the problem? You need to explain exactly what you don't know. What did you try, and what was the result?

Comment: There are no different _types of JSONarray_... First suggestion: http://www.json.org/ Second suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474382/read-values-from-json-object

Comment: I suppose the question is "how to iterate oven an array". Use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid JavaScript object, so you can easily traverse

```
var data =[ { "id": "bar", "data": [ { "x": "info", "y": 4826 }, { "x": "error", "y": 4823 }, { "x": "warn", "y": 4751 } ] }, { "id": "pie", "data": [ { "key": "info", "y": 4826 }, { "key": "error", "y": 4823 }, { "key": "warn", "y": 4751 } ] }, { "id": "pie", "data": [ { "key": "info", "y": 510 }, { "key": "error", "y": 600 }, { "key": "warn", "y": 185 } ] } ];

for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
    console.log(data[i].id);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C3pEF/1/